# Jquery - Adding <footer> element to <bolckquotes> based on some condition

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add some text in the `<footer>` tag within `<blockquote>` tag, which is not working. I am using Bootstrap along with jQuery. Below is what I have tried so far:

**HTML:**

```
<h5>
<div class="text-green"> Done by User / Ticket Status: Booked</div>
</h5>
<blockquote id="activity-detail">Details activities</blockquote>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
<script>
.....
.....
// the note is a text value is fetched from json and console.log is logging it properly.
// Assume that note = 'This is the note text'.
if(note != ""){
                $('#activity-detail').append("<footer>" + note +"</footer>");
            }
......
......
</script>
```

**Expected Result**

Assuming that the note is not `"" (blank)`

```
<h5>
<div class="text-green"> Done by User / Ticket Status: Booked</div>
</h5>
<blockquote id="activity-detail">Details activities
  <footer>This is the note text. </footer>
</blockquote>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your javascript is in on document ready? Are you sure that DOM is completely loaded? In its case your code works

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.. it was indeed the issue. After fixing it is working.

Comment: This should work with the code you have (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/wxuuf9f1/). I would maybe try doing something like $('#activity-detail').hide() to see if it disappears - if it doesn't you know there's some reason it's not being found. Might help narrow it down at least...

Comment: Thanks Luke for looking into this. It is resolved now.